# Contour intergal of a rational trigonometric function, can't find my mistake.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, trigonometric-integrals

This is the integral :
$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{(5+4\cos x)^2}\ $$
Which, according to wolfram alpha, should evaluate to $\frac{10\pi}{27} $,
but the value i find is $\frac{20\pi}{27} $.

---

These are my calculations :

Using complex form of cosine i get $ \cos x = \frac{t^2+1}{2t}$
where $ t = e^{ix}$ and $ dx = \frac{dt}{it}$.
If $\partial{D} $ is the unit circle
$$ I = \int_{\partial{D}} \frac{-i}{t(\frac{5t+2t^2+2}{t})^2} dt = 
 -i \int_{\partial{D}}\frac{t}{(t+2)^2(t+1/2)^2}dt = -i I_a$$

$I_a = \pi i $ times the residue in -$\frac{1}{2}$

The residue is equal to 
\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d}{dz} \left( \frac{t(t+1/2)^2}{(t+2)^2(t+1/2)^2}\right) 
&= \lim_{z\to-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d}{dz}  \frac{t}{(t+2)^2} 
\\&= \lim_{z\to-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{(t+2)^2-2t(t+2)}{(t+2)^4} 
\\&= \lim_{z\to-\frac{1}{2}} \frac{2-t}{(t+2)^3} 
= \frac{2+1/2}{(-1/2+2)^3} 
\\&= \frac{5/2}{27/9} = \frac{20}{27} 
\end{align}

so $ I_a = i\pi\frac{20}{27}$

So our original integral $$I = -i I_a   =  -i^2 \pi\frac{20}{27}  =  \frac{20\pi}{27}$$

Comment: Residue theorem asks for a factor $2\pi i$ instead of $\pi i$ no?

Comment: I tought since it's on the real axis, it was $i\pi$

Comment: Did you mean to say $dx = \frac{dt}{it}$?

Comment: Yes, edited sorry.

Comment: No, the residue theorem always give $2 \pi i$.

Comment: Even if it is $2i\pi$ it gives $\frac{40\pi}{27}$. This was my first result too.

Comment: Maybe include your calculation of the residue. Did you take a derivative first (we have a pole of order 2)

Comment: Yes, i am going to edit and add the calculation.

Comment: I edited my answer and indicated how to fix your calculations.

Comment: @Math_QED : You indicated how to fix the typo in $27/9$ which should be $27/8$. The next expression used that correct fraction, thus really a typo.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't think that far. The main problem was the factorisation here.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is when using the residue theorem:

$$\oint_{C^+} f(z) dz = 2\pi i\sum_{singularities} Res(f,singularity)$$

You forgot the factor $2$ in this formula.

---

Another mistake: $$5t + 2t^2 + 2 = 2(t+2)(t+1/2)$$

You again forgot a factor 2 (which will yield a factor $4$ eventually)

---

You also made a mistake in calculating the residue.

Note that $(-1/2 + 2)^3 = (3/2)^3 = 27/8$

---

Correcting these two mistakes, we easily find the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You made an error in calculating the factorization of the denominator. You should get $$5t+2t^2+2=(2+t)(1+2t)=2(t+2)(t+1/2),$$ where you missed to transfer the leading factor $2$ to the factorized expression. The correction leads to $I=-\frac i4 I_a$ and the additional division by $4$ corrects the residuum that is computed with the correct factor $2\pi i$.

---

You could also use the geometric/binomial series to get the correct residual coefficient. Then, using $u=t+\frac12$,
$$
\frac{t}{(t+2)^2(t+\frac12)^2}=\frac{u-\tfrac12}{(u+\frac32)^2u^2}
=\frac49(u-\tfrac12)\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)\left(-\frac23\right)^ku^{k-2}
$$
so that the coefficient for the power $u^{-1}=(t+\frac12)^{-2}$ is $\frac49(1+\frac12\cdot2\cdot\frac23)=\frac{20}{27}$. The integration over the unit circle adds the factor $2\pi i$, so that in the final result $I=\frac{10\pi}{27}$.

Comment: +1 for the second method, although I think taking the limit is more straightforward.